# angular ngstyle refuses to style and is ignored

Tags: angular

angular ngstyle refuses to style.  I am trying to limit the size of a container.  On init page load I set the init width to 1100.  But using ng styles ignore the styles.  Why?

This works:

```
 <mat-card style="width:1100px;">
```

This does not work:

```
  cardwidth = 1100;  //set in TypeScript

 [style.width.px]="cardwidth"
 [style.width]="cardwidth + 'px'"
 [ngStyle]="{'width.px': cardwidth}"
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6gqrq?file=app/card-overview-example.ts. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: You probably have conflicting css rules? It seems to work fine

Comment: As said by others, it's working well, maybe conflict with external stylesheet

Comment: If conflicts are there you can use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

You have almost got it. There is a minor modification in your syntax. Instead of adding `px` to key - `width`, add it to the variable name instead as below:

**HTML:**

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'width': width + 'px'}">
    Custom width
</p>
```

**Typescript:**

```
width: string
constructor() {
    this.width = "100";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WlIXT2pBbIA4Tr67YoiU?p=preview)

Comment: Adding `.px` to the key is valid syntax according to the docs. https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle